# Trying to create a Responsive Scrolling Sticky Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create a responsive website in Dreamweaver with a header and menu which initially scroll and then stick to the top of the page.

The header and menu would need to scroll over the top of a fixed hero image.
This hero image can't be defined as a background as it will be powered by a flexslider script to change the image after a set time.

I would also like the sticky header to possibly shrink down in height when it reaches the top of the page, to reduce the amount of screen space it takes up.

I've found a number of sticky menu examples on-line and some seem to have the annoying trait where the content directly below the menu disappears behind it at the point at which the menu sticks to the top of the screen. I would like to avoid this.

[Please find a Mock-up of what I'm looking for here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPtZS.jpg)

Obviously, all of the above won't be acceptable on a mobile device.
So for mobiles, the header would need to scroll out of the way, leaving just a hamburger style menu fixed at the top of the screen.

I have found a number of examples on-line with elements of what I require, but nothing yet that combines everything.
I've tried cutting and pasting code from different sources, but haven't yet achieved the desired effect.

I don't know if what I'm asking for is workable, but I would appreciate if anyone could point me to examples of how to achieve this (or improve upon what I'm looking for).

Thanks

Neil White

Answer (score 0):

**Use this JS**

http://stickyjs.com/

it adds the class is-sticky to the element which you wanted to stick to top. So you can add height in css for is-sticky class. Which in terms will reduce or increase the height of element when it reaches to top as per your requirement.